# Listen to keypresses while pydoc.pipepager is running

Tags: python-3.x

I have a loop which shows some information to the user through pipepager. I'd like to be able to go to the next and previous iteration and also accept some other keypresses while the pipepager function is active(the information is being displayed on the terminal through less).

I think this requires some async functions.

Comment: can you add an example of what you have tried ?

Comment: I'm using less (pydoc.pipepager) so I can scroll up and down the input and also search which are part of less's functionality.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything. I'm relatively new to python.